# Importing Java Packages

Tags: java, import, package

Suppose I have following package hierarchy
**Package alpha -> Package beta -> Package gamma**

-> Represents gamma is inside beta , beta is inside alpha.

My question is :
Suppose if I write

> import alpha.*;

- Does this imports classes inside beta and gamma or just the classes inside alpha is imported?

Comment: only alpha will be imported

Comment: Why didn't you try it?

Comment: There is no recursive import. import a.*; imports the classes in a, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only the classes in `alpha` will be imported, to import all 3 you need:

```
import alpha.*;
import alpha.beta.*;
import alpha.beta.gamma.*;
```

Comment: Ok, I got to concept of Import , it imports all the classes of the mentioned package. _Thank you_ , for the clarity.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments and epoch's answer have already stated, only the classes in the named package will be imported. It's important to understand why that's the case.

Take a look at the [java.util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) package. There's a lot of classes and interfaces available in just that one package. That's a lot of classes in that package alone. If you imported `java.util.*`, you would get all of those classes/interfaces imported. That's already quite a lot of bloat.

Now imagine that calling `import java.util.*` imported all packages recursively. Now you'd also be adding all the classes found in:

- [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

  - [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)
  - [java.util.concurrent.locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html)
- [java.util.jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html)
- [java.util.logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)
- [java.util.prefs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html)
- [java.util.regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)
- [java.util.spi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/spi/package-summary.html)
- [java.util.zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)

That's a **ton** more stuff that you don't need!!!